# How can I get the last transaction from a SQL table for each Item that appears in the table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some advice on how to get the last transaction for each item out of the sql table. Additionally if an item recorded only the first or it recorded the final transaction against it, it must not appear in the list.

For example: Items have 4 transactions recorded against it with time stamps. Transactions are classified as A, B, C and D. The output must tell me the last transaction for each Item except for items that only have transaction A recorded or items that have transaction D recorded. In this case the Item should not appear in the output.

At the moment I can do it with 2 additional views and a separate table which I need to populate first and then I can get the list of items with their current status (last transaction ID). I'm still learning SQL so I am sure there must be a cleaner way to do this.

Sample Data:

| Item | TransID | DateofTransaction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | A | 2021/07/01 01:00 |
| ABC123 | B | 2021/07/01 09:38 |
| ABC123 | C | 2021/07/01 18:16 |
| ABC123 | D | 2021/07/02 02:55 |
| ABC124 | A | 2021/07/02 11:33 |
| ABC124 | B | 2021/07/02 20:12 |
| ABC125 | A | 2021/07/03 04:50 |
| ABC125 | B | 2021/07/03 13:28 |
| ABC125 | C | 2021/07/03 22:07 |
| ABC126 | A | 2021/07/04 06:45 |

Expected Result:

| Item | LastTransID | DateofTransaction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC124 | B | 2021/07/02 20:12 |
| ABC125 | C | 2021/07/03 22:07 |

Here is my current SQL code:

```
    CREATE VIEW [dbo].[dsiNBCTrack_LastTransactions]
AS
SELECT        PallNum2, MAX(DateOfCapture) AS LastTransaction
FROM            dbo.dsiNBCTrack
GROUP BY PallNum2
HAVING        (MAX(DateOfCapture) >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-10-01 00:00:00', 102))

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[dsiNBCTrack_LastStatus]
AS
SELECT DISTINCT PallNum2, LastTransaction,
(SELECT        TOP (1) TransID
FROM            dbo.dsiNBCTrack
WHERE        (PallNum2 = dbo.dsiNBCTrack_LastTransactions.PallNum2) AND (DateOfCapture = dbo.dsiNBCTrack_LastTransactions.LastTransaction)) AS TransID
FROM            dbo.dsiNBCTrack_LastTransactions
WHERE        (PallNum2 IN
(SELECT DISTINCT PallNum2
FROM            dbo.dsiNBCTrack_Active))

insert into [dcLINK_PD].[dbo].[dsiNBCTrack_Active]
  ([TransID]
      ,[BranchTo]
      ,[DateUpdated]
      ,[TimeUpdated]
      ,[DSIUser]
      ,[Item]
      ,[ItemDescription]
      ,[ShortItem]
      ,[Reason1]
      ,[LotTo]
      ,[PallNum2]
      ,[QtyTrans]
      ,[ToLoc]
      ,[LotSts]
      ,[Reason2]
      ,[Shift]
      ,[PallLineNum]
      ,[LineNum] 
      ,[DateOfCapture]
      ,[UOM])
 SELECT  [TransID]
      ,[BranchTo]
      ,[DateUpdated]
      ,[TimeUpdated]
      ,[DSIUser]
      ,[Item]
      ,[ItemDescription]
      ,[ShortItem]
      ,[Reason1]
      ,[LotTo]
      ,[PallNum2]
      ,[QtyTrans]
      ,[ToLoc]
      ,[LotSts]
      ,[Reason2]
      ,[Shift]
      ,[PallLineNum]
      ,[LineNum]
      ,[DateOfCapture]
      ,[UOM]
FROM            dbo.dsiNBCTrack
where (transid = 'B')
and DateOfCapture >= '2020/10/02'
and PallNum2 not in (SELECT distinct PallNum2
FROM            dbo.dsiNBCTrack WITH (nolock)
WHERE        (TransID = 'D') AND (DateOfCapture >= '2020/10/02'))
order by (select Transid from dsiNBCTrack_LastStatus where PallNum2 = dbo.dsiNBCTrack.PallNum2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you could do this with `ROW_NUMBER` and a windowed `COUNT` to help the filtering:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT Item,
           TransID,
           DateofTransaction,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY DateofTransaction DESC) AS RN,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN TransID NOT IN ('A','D') THEN 1 END) OVER  (PARTITION BY Item) AS NotAD --REad that it must have at least one transaction that isn't A or D
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT Item,
       TransID,
       DateofTransaction
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
  AND NotAD > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance @Larnu. So obviously I tried t simplify the problem to be able to post the question. Now I adapted your code to work with my exact transid's.

`COUNT(CASE WHEN TransID NOT IN ('SD', 'SP','CA') and TransID IN ('RS', 'IL') THEN 1 END)`

The sequence is for transID can be: 
LC, (LS), RS, (PA), (IT), SP/SD/CA
IL, (PA), (IT), SP/SD/CA

SO I need the last transid if Item has:
RS and no SP,SD or CA
IL  and no SP,SD or CA

With my change I still see records with SD, SP

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps to what you are trying to do. The first is taking only those TransIDs that have more than one entry. The second is to then take the last row per group.

For the first you can filter your table using `HAVING COUNT > 1`.

For the second, I would suggest ordering the remaining rows by TransIDs and by DateOfTransaction. You can then

- use `OVER PARTITION BY` to get 'subgroups' for each transaction. Make sure to order desc
- then use `ROWNUMBER()` to assign a number to each row in each of the 'subgroups'
- and finally use `WHERE ROWNUMBER() = 1` to get the first (since you ordered desc this is the last) row.